# Module twin coming back empty

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am trying to set the desired properties on a Module's device twin, but when I retrieve the twin from the IoT Hub, it comes back full of nulls.

```
var moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var moduleTwin = await moduleClient.GetTwinAsync();
```

When I inspect moduleTwin in the debugger I get

[image: debugger showing all properties as null]

The connection string is the one for the module, copied from the IoT Hub.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. So this issue is expected.

From module app, only has permission to read desired properties and read/write reported properties. See the following:

[image]

To access all module twin, you can do it from solution back end and require the ServiceConnect permission. Module twin is newly added. You need Microsoft.Azure.Devices V1.16.0-preview-001 or later. The following is a console app sample.

```
        RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        Module module;

        var moduleTwin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceID, moduleID);
```

[image]

Reference:

[understand and use module twins in IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-module-twins)

"[Get started with IoT Hub module identity and module twin using .NET back end and .NET device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-module-twin-getstarted)"